# How do you sum every nth column of data in gnuplot?

Tags: gnuplot, average, data-processing

I would like to take an average over several columns of a data set in Gnuplot. The problem is that I want to average every other column (starting from the second column of my dataset). I was thinking of using every somehow but I still don't really understand when and where to use every. To help visualise my question: my data looks something like this:

```
x  y1  z1  y2  z2
2  0.6  0  0.6  0
1  0.7  0  0.7  1
1  0.8  2  0.8  1
1  0.9  0  0.9  0
```

and I would like to average y1 and y2 and plot the result by doing something like:

```
stats filename nooutput
plot filename u 1:sum[col = every :2::2::STATS_columns] / ((STATS_columns-1)/2)
```

Not sure if this is anywhere close to doable though. Also, it would be nice to have a way of finding the number of columns used without any apriori knowledge of what the data looks like. In the example I have used my knowledge of the data to know that the average is over ((STATS_columns-1)/2) number of points.

Thank you for your response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your code I assume you want to average y1 and y2 for each row and then plot it versus x (column 1). Since you have several identical x values, there would be another average, namely an average over the columns and over all identical x values.
I modified your data to better illustrate the difference.
I guess you were asking fot the red circles. The blue triangles are basically the average of the average, i.e. the average of the red points.
Check `help summation` and `help smooth`. `sum` has no step size with the index.
From gnuplot help:

```
sum [<var> = <start> : <end>] <expression>
```

**Code:**

```
### average over columns and smooth
reset session

$Data <<EOD
#x  y1  z1  y2  z2
1  2.0  0  4.0  0
1  2.2  0  4.2  1
1  2.9  2  4.9  1
2  2.1  0  4.1  0
2  2.3  0  4.3  0
2  2.8  0  4.8  0
3  2.2  0  4.2  0
3  2.3  0  4.3  0
3  2.7  0  4.7  0
EOD

stats $Data nooutput
set offsets 0.5,0.5,0.5,0.5

Count = (STATS_columns-1)/2
plot $Data u 1:((sum[i=1:Count] column(i*2))/Count) w p pt 7 lc rgb "red" ti "average over y1,y2 columns for each row",\
     $Data u 1:((sum[i=1:Count] column(i*2))/Count) smooth unique w p pt 9 lc rgb "blue" ti "average over y1,y2 for each x"
### end of code
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: Great! Thanks for your help. I looked at sum help online but didn't really understand how to use it properly, especially for a case like this. BTW the x values came out like that by accident... My x values increment with a constant step. The second average is still useful to know about though. Thanks!

Comment: I did, but my vote isn't recorded because my reputation is still too low.

Comment: Just realised I could also click on the tick to mark it useful. Just did that.